# How to reset Github upload settings in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, version-control

I have quite a weird problem with uploading my android studio project to Github. I don't have so much experience with VCS but i worked with a few projects via VCS in past and everything worked fine...

I wanted to upload my project to Github repo. The problem is that when i checked it on Github site the project structure is kinda weird. It doesn't look as usually.
[The weird structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo4Xv.jpg)

The folder where i typically find MainActivity.java and other files is empty as you can see below.

[Empty folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUazx.jpg)

I suppose that there is some kind of mistake in my config in Android Studio. I realize that it would be difficult to find where exactly the problem is. I just want to find some way how to reset that VCS settings to default and upload it to another repository. Do you have some idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is to look at the path Android Studio has set for your github folder, might be that it is wrong and therefor giving you this weird result.

Comment: Actually, i checked it again. That's not my case. Do you have some idea how to simply delete the GIT setings in folder with my project and set a new local git which i can upload to new repository . I quess it can be easier than find an exact problem.... I dont have any other idea how to solve that....

Comment: Maybe these links can help you:  https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/ or http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. Furtunately I solved it. The solution was kinda simply. I just moved content of local folder to another location. Then i pushed empty folder. At the end i just moved the content back and pushed it again. Then I checked if there are that files which i had missed before. Everything was OK. Thank you one more time, guys.